# How do I convert a child node to a parent node in a GXT treepanel?

Tags: gxt

Here, I am creating gxt tree with rood node. I dont have any data to fill the tree initially.

In the screen I have gxt grid. Drag and drop from the grid to the tree. After droping from the grid, for the data I have context menu. In the context menu selection listener I have to make this data to parent node which can accept child nodes.

```
FolderEnv[] folders = new FolderEnv[] {
    new FolderEnv(
        "Environment Hierarchy", new FolderEnv[] {})

};

FolderEnv root = new FolderEnv("root");
for (int i = 0; i < folders.length; i++) {
    root.add((FolderEnv) folders[i]);
}

treeStore.add(root.getChildren(), true);
```

Comment: PLEASE DON'T SHOUT. :-) [PMF](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2905768/pmf) and I have fixed it for you on this occasion. Also, "i" is always "I", and please do make use of the code formatting button in the editor toolbar and the preview below the editor letting you see how your question will appear. (Sorry to say I don't know the answer to the question, or I'd post one, so cleanup is all I can do to help.)

Comment: It seems you asked twice almost the same question there is no need to, it won't help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24379420/how-to-create-gxt-tree-with-empty-root-node-that-can-accept-childs